# Producing hydrogen sulfide at home - how dangerous is it?

Tags: home-experiment, safety

When I was a kid, I used to go to the pharmacy to buy sulfur and iron powder, then mix it together and heat it until it starts to react into iron sulfide. Put a chunk of iron sulfide into some vinegar, and you get a room smelling badly of rotten eggs. This experiment was also described in some "chemistry for kids" boxes from the 80's.

Now I'd like to do this experiment with my son, but in the meantime I learned that hydrogen sulfide is a very potent poison, even more poisonous than hydrocyanic acid. For this reason, I'd like to set up some precautions.

Of course I won't do it in a closed room, and I won't let my son breathe in much of the gas.

The gas can be smelled long before it starts to get dangerous, so I think it should be pretty easy to use an amount of sulfur and iron that will cause the characteristic smell, but at the same time is guaranteed to not cause any danger. So, I'm looking for some quantitative estimation:

How much iron sulfide would be enough to create a dangerous amount of hydrogen sulfide? To make the calculation easier, let's assume we grind the iron sulfide and use a stronger acid than vinegar, so that all of the gas will be created almost instantly.

If possible, it would be great to have two estimations: one of the beginning of the "danger zone", and one of the beginning of the "lethal zone". According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_sulfide#Safety), the gas starts to smell at $\pu{0.00047ppm}$, the danger zone starts at about $\pu{10 ppm}$, and at about $\pu{320 ppm}$ it can be lethal.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but as long as you do it outdoors, I have a hard time seeing now you will reach any lethal amounts. You'll likely puke your guts out way before that happens, and if you start puking your guts out, it is about time to abort mission.

Comment: Can you tolerate the smell of rotten eggs?

Comment: In our lab practicals (where we had to work with hydrogen sulfide), we have been told not to rely on our sense of smell, which could become dull over time. Take care to get ventilated.

Comment: @StianYttervik Note that you can't count on the smell of the gas, since at high concentrations, the gas paralyzes your olfactory receptors, so you won't smell anything when it starts to become dangerous. Yes, I also don't expect to reach lethal amounts, I've done the experiment many times, but anyway, I want to have some quantitative estimation.

Comment: @StianYttervik "... if you start puking your guts out, it is about time to abort mission." I wish someone had told me that when I started university.

Comment: @cheesussaysstopfiringmods Uh, yes you can. You most certainly can. If you choose to stay there, revolted and alarmed, then over time your sense of smell will disappear. Or, if you suddenly walk into a room with >100ppm you could theoretically also not smell it. But rest assured, all the way up to olfactory paralysis will be a foul smelling fight against your desire to leave. And as I said, as long as you are *outdoors* where lethal concentrations are unlikely to hang around.

Comment: The main rule of chemistry for kids boxes is to use the minimal amount required to demonstrate an effect. Something littler than a a little pinch will suffice so go ahead. I guess prank vials also contain H2S. They were common when I was a kid :)) for carnival

Comment: You might look for the paper strip mentioned here for a round elegant :) experiment - evolution then capture of the gas. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/126728/indicator-for-h2s

Comment: Not dangerous to me at all, because I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

On the question as to how dangerous is H2S let me detail some facts that I find problematic. [Here is a good paper](http://www.euro.who.int/__data/assets/pdf_file/0019/123076/AQG2ndEd_6_6Hydrogensulfide.PDF).

I summarize some of my findings:

First, H2S after initial exposure can deaden your sense of smell (10-minute exposure at 50-100 ppm impairs the sense of smell). So, one may not really have an accurate conception of the magnitude of one's time exposure to the gas.

Second, skin exposure may be a path to ingestion, especially if moist I suspect. Note, some sources actually disagreed on skin exposure poisoning of Hydrogen sulfide with one study alluring to skin toxicosis from high concentrations over a long period.

Third, following a significant exposure event, the very fact that you are still alive should not be comforting. People having incurred a lethal dose may be a de facto walking dead with a slow hourly progression to death.

Fourth, the ppm considered fatal for H2S is not that far removed from some known very toxic gases (like HCN). However, my opening reference doubts if one can even assign accurate figures on ingestion via the lungs. Here is an extract addressing dosing level ranges:

> Findings in the canary, cat, dog, goat, guinea pig, rabbit and rat (2) are consistent as to the effects of hydrogen sulfide: at 150-225 mg/m3 signs of local irritation of eyes and throat after many hours of exposure; at 300-400 mg/m3 eye and mucous membrane irritation in 1 hour and slight general effects with longer exposure; at 750-1000 mg/m3 slight systemic symptoms in less than 1 hour and possible death after several hours; at 1350 mg/m3 grave systemic effects within 30 minutes and death in less than 1 hour; at 2250 mg/m3 collapse and death within 15-30 minutes, and at 2700 mg/m3 immediate collapse, respiratory paralysis and death.

Viewing all these together, if one has a choice to avoid working or experimenting with the gas, I would do so.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure if I understand your last sentence. As long as you safely stay within some reasonable quantities which are *far* from the lethal ones, why would you want to avoid experimenting with the gas? It might be even a safety advantage if students know how the gas smells. Not everyone knows how "rotten eggs" actually smell.

Comment: To answer your question, some professionals (with safety gear), including, for example, sewer workers, still manage to die from toxic exposure. Hence, my speculation of moist skin (especially someone working in hot humid conditions) being a not clearly specified route to ingestion. Also, read my cited reference on the attack of organs including the brain,  now that is troubling.

Comment: If one decides that working in targetted safe ranges with H2S is the best and safest alternative, that is keeping, I believe, with working with good judgment. However, at times experiments may involve errors (like in quantities employed) and thus may result in an accidental exposure. With that in mind as a forethought, was there another path not employing H2S?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air), at sea level, 20°C warm air has a density of $1.20 kg/m^3$. 78% of it is Dinitrogen, which under the same conditions has a density of $1.17 kg/m^3$. To simplify the calculations, we will assume that the air is 100% dinitrogen, which is a reasonable simplification because the density is so similar. So a cubic meter of air weighs $1.17kg$, and because $N_2$ [has a molar mass](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-calculate-the-molar-mass-of-nitrogen-gas) of $28.014$, we have $41.76$ moles of dinitrogen in a $m^3$.

To produce enough hydrogen sulfide for $1000$ ppm in one cubic meter, we would thus need about $0.041$ moles of $H_2S$ (neglecting the density of $H_2S$, since there is so much more $N_2$). With a [molecular mass of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_sulfide#Safety) $34.08g / mol$, this means $1.39 g$ of $H_2S$ in one cubic meter of air is about $1000$ ppm.

$88$% of the weight of $H_2S$ comes from the sulfur, so we need roughly $1.23$ grams of sulfur to create this amount of $H_2S$.

I hope this is more or less correct.